# ggplot2 to create multiple plots but without a facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I want to plot four independent (in 2 rows and 2 columns) plots, each with a different flipped x axis. I have used `ggplot` with a `face_wrap` but this approach doesn't give each plot its own flipped x-axis labels.

Is there a way to achieve my goal in ggplot2?

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/surv.csv')

names(data)[2:5] <- c("Representation", "Solidification", "Application", "Confidence")

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
  mutate(name = name, 
         value = str_wrap(value, 50)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(value, fill = name), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(.~name) + 
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y = "Students", x = "") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=8))
```

[image]

Comment: You could create 4 plots and use `patchwork`

Comment: Your question title seems to be about `without a facet_wrap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `scales = 'free_y'` to your original code.

Edit: add code to manually change order of the levels.

```
level_order <- c("Neutral",
                  "Agree",
                  "Strongly Agree",
                  "The assignment gave me a great opportunity to\napply what I learned",
                  "The assignment gave me an opportunity to apply\nwhat I learned",     
                  "The assignment helped me solidify the key concepts",                 
                  "The assignment highly helped me solidify the key\nconcepts",        
                  "The assignment highly reflected the class\ninstructions",          
                  "The assignment reflected the class instructions",                    
                  "The assignment somewhat reflected the class\ninstructions") 

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
  mutate(name = name, 
         value = str_wrap(value, 50),
         value = factor(value, levels = level_order)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(value, fill = name), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(.~name, scales = 'free_y') + 
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y = "Students", x = "") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=8))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In the "confidence" plot is there a way for "Neutral" to show below "Agree"?

Comment: The way to do this is reorder the factor levels in `value` before piping into `ggplot`

Comment: Thanks, I ask that as another question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest next approach:

```
#Code
library(tidyverse)

data <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/surv.csv')

names(data)[2:5] <- c("Representation", "Solidification", "Application", "Confidence")
```

The option 1 would be adjusting `facet_wrap()`:

```
#Option 1
data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
  mutate(name = name, 
         value = str_wrap(value, 50)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(value, fill = name), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales='free') + 
  labs(y = "Students", x = "") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=8))
```

And the second option would be create a list and a function for the plots:

```
#Option 2
data2 <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
  mutate(name = name, 
         value = str_wrap(value, 50))
#Split
LData2 <- split(data2,data2$name)
#Now function to plot
myfun <- function(x)
{
  mplot <- ggplot(x,aes(value, fill = name)) + 
    geom_bar(show.legend = FALSE) + 
    labs(y = "Students", x = "") +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=8))+
    ggtitle(unique(x$name))
  
  return(mplot)
}
#Apply
Lplots <- lapply(LData2,myfun)
```

Some example output:

```
#Example
Lplots[[1]]
```

[image]

Or using `patchwork` with `wrap_plots()` in the list:

```
library(patchwork)
#Code
wrap_plots(Lplots)
```

Output:

[image]

Or changing the axis orientation and using `patchwork`:

```
#Now function to plot 2
myfun <- function(x)
{
  mplot <- ggplot(x,aes(value, fill = name)) + 
    geom_bar(show.legend = FALSE) + 
    labs(y = "Students", x = "") +
    coord_flip()+
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=8))+
    ggtitle(unique(x$name))
  
  return(mplot)
}
#Apply
Lplots <- lapply(LData2,myfun)
#Wrap
wrap_plots(Lplots)
```

Output:

[image]